# A word becomes imaginary

Tags: riddle, mathematics, language

I'm important in geometry
If you add a letter, you get the German translation
If you re-order the letters of the English word and add brackets () and multiply, it becomes imaginary
If you re-order the letters of the German word and add brackets () and multiply, it becomes real

Find the word with the above properties.

Comment: What's "Englisch"?

Comment: It's a typo - I corrected it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> A line!

This is because

> 1. Lines are quite important in geometry...

> 2. linie is the German translation of "line"

> 3. $i \cdot \ln(e)=i$ which is imaginary

> 4. $i \cdot i \cdot \ln(e)=-1$ which is real!

Comment: perfect answer!